# Is there a way to use my own account for a twitch chatbot?

Tags: javascript, chatbot, twitch

I am actually coding a bot that sends into a chat the text I send in a discord channel. I think I need to use a twitch bot account for it to work, because tmi.js authentication needs a token, but is there a way for me to use my own twitch account instead ?
I would like to code it with JavaScript, with tmi.js but I can use another way if needed.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Sure you can also get a token for your own account, not a bot account

Comment: It's nice to learn that ! Do you know how I can get an account token?

Comment: https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/irc says "*The account (username) that the chatbot uses […] can be your Twitch account.*" and "*Generate [the oauth token] with https://twitchapps.com/tmi/*". It doesn't seem there is any distinction between bot accounts and user accounts.

Comment: Thank you ! I thought applications were sort of bot accounts.

Comment: I don't think you want to write an application that anybody can permit accessing their account. I suppose you could do that as well, but it seems unnecessary for a chat bot that doesn't need to access account data (other than its own).